# Google Spreadsheet - Number of working days between two dates in Google Script except holiday

Tags: date, spreadsheet, days

Can anyone help me with how to calculate a number of days between two days (except Sat, Sun and Holiday) days between two dates?

The Google spreadsheet is below when I select Completed at Column C, Column D will show current day, but how can I

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kaYpK9LNxXptXf5WVHstYQdQm2Lc8aDoh778-I0EgoQ/edit#gid=0

```js
/**
* Date Stamp for Task Completion and Number of Days, When Status is Updated to Complete.
*/

//CORE VARIABLES
// The column you want to check if something is entered.
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 3;
// Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,1];
// Sheet you are working on
var SHEETNAME = 'PROJECTS'
// Value condition.
var VALUETOCHECK = 'Completed';
// InComing date column
var INCOMINGDATE = 1;
// Complated date column
var COMPLATEDATE = 4;
// Working days column
var WORKINGDAYLOCATION = [0,1];
 
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
//checks that we’re on the correct sheet.
if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) {
var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
//checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.
if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) {
if(selectedCell.getValue() == VALUETOCHECK){
var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
dateTimeCell.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "MMMM dd"))

}
}
}
}
```

calculate working days between there two days at Column E.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Script below is working good, but the smart way!
  /**
    * Date Stamp for Task Completion and Number of Days, When Status is Updated to Complete.
    */

```
//CORE VARIABLES
// The column you want to check if something is entered.
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 3;
// Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,1];
// Sheet you are working on
var SHEETNAME = 'PROJECTS'
// Value condition.
var VALUETOCHECK = 'Completed';
// InComing date column
var INCOMINGDATE = 1;
// Complated date column
var COMPLATEDATE = 4;
// Working days column
var WORKINGDAYLOCATION = [0,2];


function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
//checks that we’re on the correct sheet.

//checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.

if (sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME) {
  var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
  var dayNumberCell = selectedCell.offset(WORKINGDAYLOCATION[0],WORKINGDAYLOCATION[1]);
  if (selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK){
  if (selectedCell.getValue() == VALUETOCHECK) {
    dateTimeCell.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "MMMM dd"));
    var incomeRow = selectedCell.getRow();
    dayNumberCell.setValue("=NETWORKDAYS(A" + incomeRow + ",D" + incomeRow + ",TempDataSet!Y2:Y17)");
  }
  else
  {
    dateTimeCell.setValue("");
    dayNumberCell.setValue("");
  }

}
  return 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In cell E1, put in `=NETWORKDAYS(C1, D1)`.
In E2, `=NETWORKDAYS(C2, D2)`, and so on so forth.

For more information, see this [link](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092979?hl=en&ref_topic=3105385).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but the Rows will be removed once tasks are done. so it will not work.